# How do I store and access my API keys with a React + Webpack app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently building a project with React, Babel and Webpack on the front end.

I'll need to store and access my API keys somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

I think I should store my API keys in my .env file, which is in my .gitignore. But it's accessing them that's tricking me up.

From what I've read it seems that webpack can access environment variables in yuor .env file.

But if I do that, won't it mean that when I make requests my API keys will be going through the browser - so the keys will be unprotected?

In the past I've used a node express back end server, so that my API keys are protected and have nothing to do with the browser. But I'm not sure if I need this when I have a webpack dev server as well.

I started to set up a node express back end server, but then didn't know how to tie this into my webpack.config or package.json. Webpack is already a node express server! So do I have 2 servers? With the sole reason for having a second server being to protect my API keys?

I'm really confusing myself and I think unnecessarily complicating things.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an express server to make the API calls with the key and serve the same response. Using the express server as an intermediary this way, you will never have to expose the API key on the client side.

EDIT: didn't read that you already thought about it

In that case, you can use webpack-dev-middleware (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) and use just one express server to serve the API and static files.

Your code might look like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config.dev');
// require keys

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    // api logic
)}

app.get(/^(?!\/api).*$/, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```